# Is there a way to test private methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, private-methods, react-testing-library

I have a React component 'A'. One method 'foo' inside it is passed as a prop to component 'B'. foo is triggered on click of component B.

Question - How to test this foo method?

I can circumvent this problem by making the method foo as public and testing it separately. But I do not want to make it public.
Another way which I tried and did not work is triggering the click event in component B hoping it would call the foo method. Not sure if it is possible and if possible how!

```
const A = () => {
    const foo = () => {console.log('Clicked!')}
    return (
      <B clickTrigger={foo} />
    )
}
```

Comment: What is your test subject component A or B? What are you looking to test? The component behavior, or actually the method? Usually, "private" members are implementation details...

Comment: The test subject is component A. I want to test the private member.

Comment: What will `foo` do in your real app?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to test that the click is causing some change in the component, rather than just checking that the method is called.

You can render component `A`, fire a click event, and make assertions based on how that causes changes in the component's output. Here's what a test could look like, using `react-testing-library`:

```js
test('does a thing when clicked', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<A />);
  // This assumes you have a button inside component B
  // that has `foo` as the onClick:
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Click me'));
  // Make assertions here based on how the click handler
  // causes the component's output to change, generally based
  // on some text changing
  expect(getByText('You clicked the button')).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the code executed inside the foo function. 
Thanks to this mock, you will be able to test of your foo function has been successfully called .

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get hold of a reference inside a closure, so you'd have to export it to your test framework somehow.  There's a pattern that uses WeakMaps for storing private state, and if the test framework has access to the WeakMap it can look inside, while other objects without that reference can't.

```
let p = new WeakMap();
const A = () => {
    let foo = p.get(A);
    return (
        <B clickTrigger={foo} />
    );
};
p.set(A, () => {console.log('Clicked!')});

// Export A and p to testing framework but just A to clients
```